# Align figures in tabular environment with text

Tags: tables, floats, arrays

I have two picture that I want to align it with the text next to it from top, i used this code:

```
\documentclass[3p,onecolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section*{Virtual}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{l p{11cm}}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{black}&\lipsum[1].\\
\vspace{1cm}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{black}&\lipsum[2].\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't align with it. how can I fix it??
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the bottom of the `\includegraphics` is aligned to the baseline, whereas the bottom of the 1st line of text also sits on the baseline.  The image must be shifted down by its height (`\height`) and then up by the height of one row of text above the baseline (`\ht\strutbox`).

```
\documentclass[3p,onecolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section*{Virtual}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{l p{11cm}}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}&\lipsum[1].\\
\vspace{1cm}\\
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}&\lipsum[2].\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]